# Getting the full source code from Visual Studio for licensing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

In order to license my software, the licensing authority asks for the "first 25 and last 25" pages of my source code.

I have completed my project using .NET MVC framework in Visual Studio, where I have a solution with 9 projects.

How do you think would I able to get the full source code as text so I can copy and paste it? Or do I have to copy and paste each model references, controllers, view controllers and view pages separately, which does not make sense to me.

Can you please give me advice on how to address this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Who is that *licensing authority*?

Comment: Licensing authority in Turkey? Why did you ask?

Comment: It isn't normal to license your own software from someone else, and the request for copies of your source code, partial or whole, is odd. That's most likely why he asked. If he hadn't, I would. Are you *sure* you read those licensing requirements correctly? And why do you need to "license your software" with someone else? Surely you should license *out* your own software to other people? And just to be clear, the only part about your question that makes sense is that this (whole thing) doesn't make sense.

Comment: What I meant by licensing is getting copyright protection. Sorry if there is a confusion over terms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a Powershell in your project root.

You can get the first 250 lines this way:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.cs" -Recurse | Get-Content | select -First 250
```

Or the last ones this way:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.cs" -Recurse | Get-Content | select -Last 250
```

It is basically doing this:

- Get all file names and filter them by `*.cs` (C# Files)
- Get their content
- Select the first / last few lines

I asked *Who is that licensing authority*, because this sounds crazy. Are you sure you unterstand them right?

Comment: What I meant by licensing authority is copyright protection. I cannot patent my software, but they allow me to get copyright protection for it to prevent it from being used anywhere else